# Rails, Grape entity throws: uninitialized constant Grape::Entity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-grape

In rails project, I made `api` folder and I added this code to my `application.rb` file:

```
config.paths.add File.join('app', 'api'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]
```

In my `api` folder I have created `game_server.rb` file:

```
module GameServer

  module Entities
   class Test < Grape::Entity
     expose :id
   end
  end


class API < Grape::API
   version 'v1', using: :path
   prefix :api
   format :json

   get :details do
      present Basis.all, with: GameServer::Entities::Test
   end

 end
end
```

All code inside `GameServer` module. When I hit `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/details` in my browser I het this error:
`uninitialized constant Grape::Entity`.

I even tried to put my `Entities` module in other file, still does not work.

WHY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old version of grape, change your grape version:

```
gem 'grape', '~> 0.11.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this repository: https://github.com/philcallister/rails-grape-entity

Just add

> gem 'grape'
>
> gem 'grape-entity'

into your `Gemfile`